# Rendering view with download link files using rails and dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, dropbox, link-to

I am kinda new in RoR and I am having some problems, hopefully you guys can help me.

In the controller:

```
def process
   @order = Order.includes({folders: :document}, {folders: :service}).find(params[:order_id])
end
```

In the view:

```
-@order.folders.each do |folder|

  p
        b one: 
        | #{folder.service[:title]}_#{folder.service[:description]}_# {folder.service[:ink]}          

        b two:  
        | #{folder[:amount]}

  h3 three
  ==@order.folders[0][:description]

  h3 four
  -@order.folders[0].document.each do |document|
        a[href= "#{document.file.url(download: true)}"] #{document[:file_file_name]}
```

This works "fine". It show the download links perfectly but the rendering of the view takes to much time.

here is the log with 2 link files:

```
Started GET "/orders/ver_detalles?order_id=297" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-25 22:17:42 -0430
Processing by OrdersController#ver_detalles as JS
  Parameters: {"order_id"=>"297"}`enter code here`
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 9  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mOrder Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id` = 297 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mOrder Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id` = 297 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mFolder Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `folders`.* FROM `folders` WHERE `folders`.`order_id` IN (297)
  [1m[36mDocument Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `documents`.* FROM `documents` WHERE `documents`.`folder_id` IN (326)[0m
  [1m[35mService Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services` WHERE `services`.`id` IN (1)
  Rendered partials/_detallesOrden.html.slim (4703.1ms)
  Rendered orders/ver_detalles.js.erb (4718.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4750ms (Views: 4734.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

here is the log with 4 link files:

```
Started GET "/orders/ver_detalles?order_id=303" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-25 22:13:31 -0430
Processing by OrdersController#ver_detalles as JS
  Parameters: {"order_id"=>"303"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 9  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mOrder Exists (15.6ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id` = 303 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mOrder Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `orders`.* FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id` = 303 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mFolder Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `folders`.* FROM `folders` WHERE `folders`.`order_id` IN (303)
  [1m[36mDocument Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `documents`.* FROM `documents` WHERE `documents`.`folder_id` IN (332, 333)[0m
  [1m[35mService Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `services`.* FROM `services` WHERE `services`.`id` IN (7, 4)
  Rendered partials/_detallesOrden.html.slim (8453.1ms)
  Rendered orders/ver_detalles.js.erb (8453.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8500ms (Views: 8484.4ms | ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)
```

So when the query returns more files the rendering takes more time. If I comment the last line in the view the rendering only takes 60ms. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can include them like this association using the following syntax:

```
    def process
       @order = Order.includes(folders: [:document, :service]).find(params[:order_id])
    end
```

Looks like your partials are doing some heavy duty work and they are taking the most of time required to complete the request:

```
  Rendered partials/_detallesOrden.html.slim (8453.1ms)
  Rendered orders/ver_detalles.js.erb (8453.1ms)
```

This suffers the partial loading overhead for every row in your `@order.folders[0].document.each` loop. So, the bigger the size of the documents, longer it takes to render the view.

I would suggest you to look for caching strategies like [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) if you can use in your partial. That would save you a lot of time and overhead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I try the fragment caching but is the same, the view take to much time in render.

Comment: If you loop through a huge amount of files, it will take time. So, you have to come up with some alternatives and see how you can minimize the heavy liftings in views, e,g, look for if you can split the views in multiple partials.